# Scraper Find element by text

Tags: go, goquery

for example, I have next table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      First
    </td>
    <td>
      1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Second
    </td>
    <td>
      2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

how can I find element by text, for example "Second" and then get value "2"?

Of course, I can do something like

```
doc, _ := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(resp.Body)
caseSize := doc.Find("tr").Each(func(i int, element *goquery.Selection){
  // here I check each element by needed text
})
```

but maybe there is may be another, more simple way, some specific finder?

Comment: Put the solution in an answer to the question, and not in your question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

As goQuery uses jQuery finders, I changed goQuery finder in a next way

```
doc.Find("tr:contains('Second')").Find("td").First().Next().Text()
```